# "leverage 'x' with 'y'"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, collocation

I read through other questions regarding the use of "leverage" and wonder if you can "leverage one resource with another? For example "Leverage our resources with your own to help you gain market share."

I prefer not to use "balance."

Comment: What do you intend *leverage* to mean? Have you checked a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You could, though you'd be at two metaphorical removes from the source of the word.

Unless the "resources" you are talking of using is borrowed capital, then your use of *leverage* would be a metaphorical comparison to that.

That word in itself is not completely divorced from the image of a physical lever.

It's a bit of a stretch.

Note that *leverage* has a sense "to use to maximum advantage", which we get by just abandoning the use of *with*:

> Leverage our resources **and** your own to help you gain market share.

Or:

> Leverage our resources **combined with** your own to help you gain market share.

Comment: "With" and not "against?" 

 - Faced with the prospect of having to pay sellers significant termination fees in connection with their failure to close a deal, many buyers are invoking the 'material adverse change' (MAC) or 'material adverse effect' clauses in their merger agreements in an attempt to abandon transactions without liability or as **leverage against** the seller to reduce the purchase price.

 [From a business law quarterly](http://example.com)

Comment: @livresque there *against* is about opposition: The seller will not want to reduce the price, the buyer does.

Answer (score 1):

This may, under some circumstances, be very proper.

*Leverage* entered financial jargon in the 19th century to describe the advantage of gambling with other people's money.

Suppose you invest $1,000 dollars in a stock. The stock goes up 10%, you make $100. Your metaphorical 'lever' is the same length on both sides of the fulcrum. $1,000 of cash buys $1,000 of stock.

But if your broker allows you to purchase on a 10% margin, you buy $10,000 worth of stock - the broker lends you the other 90% against the stock as collateral. Now if the stock goes up, you make $1,000. You've  made your metaphorical 'lever' that much longer - you've 'leveraged' your resources with his.

Of course if the stock goes *down* 10%, you've now lost your entire $1,000, instead of just $100. Leverage works both ways.